# How do I prevent direct access of a jsp through a url?

Tags: java

I am working on a web application in java. To prevent direct access of a url, I have used the code that checks for session validation. Its a customer-employee app.

In every page except the login page, I have the same header where the menu items are generated dynamically using session, depending on the role. However, when the employee accesses the url directly, it should be only accessible by a customer, the url is still accessible. It should not be like this.

How can I prevent an employee from direct access to a jsp using the url which is only valid for customer ?

Comment: What is the question? Can you share your work so far?

Answer (score 2):

apply Filter,

```
public class SessionCheck implements Filter

{
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
        if(null==((String) request.getSession().getAttribute("SESSION_PARAM_CUSTOMERID")) || ((String) request.getSession().getAttribute("SESSION_PARAM_CUSTOMERID")).equals(""))
        {
            response.sendRedirect(PAGE_SIGN_IN);
            return;
        }
        arg2.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    com.mycomp.filter.SessionCheck
  </filter-class>
</filter>
```

Map your each secure request url with filter mapping tag, as below given.

```
 <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/personal-info</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand your need is,

1. any unaunthenticated user comes -------display------>Login page
2. authenticated user with role Customer -----display------>Menu Items related to Customer
3. authenticated user with role Employee -----display------>Menu Items related to Employee

In this case, what I think you should do is,

when person enters the URL at that point, check the session is true/set or not.
for this, you can set any variable like userName as key.

if session is not set then display common Login Page and after authentication set userName key into session, not otherwise.

if session is set(you can check the userName key again to validate session exist or not), then check the role of the user,

if User belongs to role CUSTOMER ------> work accordingly.
if User belongs to role EMPLOYEE ------> work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Filter to allow only authenticated requests to access resources

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if the session is valid.
You need to check one of the session parameters e.g. username or customer ID.